# ASP.NET jQuery unobtrusive model validation injecting data-val-required without required data annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-validation

Why is my strongly type html having a data-val-required attribute even though I didn't specified in my model property to be required? Here is my model class

```
public class Document
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the html being rendered:

```
<input class="full-width" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsConfirmed field is required." id="Document_0__IsConfirmed" name="Document.IsConfirmed" type="checkbox" value="true" title="" autocomplete="off" />
<input name="Document.IsConfirmed" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Because its typeof `bool` which must always have a value (`true` or `false`). If it was `bool?` then the `data-val` attributes would not be rendered

Comment: Hi Stephen, Thanks for that, didn't thought of that before I asked the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your model to this

```
public class Document
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsConfirmed { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Arvaan, Thanks for this, the rendered html is now correct.